# What is the time complexity of this hash function?

Tags: hash, big-o, time-complexity

I have a hashing function and I want to know if it is constant.  Since the length of the array word is constant, does that mean the function is constant in Big O notation?

```
public int hash(String s) {
    if (s.length() > 7)
        return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
        if (word[i].compareTo(s) == 0)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `word` is never defined so what would `word.length` mean?

Comment: You should use `equals(s)` instead of `compareTo(s) == 0`. Also, that seems to be a very bad hashing function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the length of the array word is constant, does that mean the function is constant in Big O notation?

Big O is used to describe how the run time or memory consumption of a process grows as its input grows. If your array is of constant length, then it will not grow and have an effect. Therefore, you can in this context consider `hash()` to run in O(1), assuming that the string comparisons are done in relatively constant time.

One way to think about it would be to say that since the length of the array is not variable, it should always be possible to "unroll" that loop so as to have a fixed number of O(1) comparisons one after the other, which all-in-all will still be O(1). Again, this presumes that the time taken to compare the strings is also constant (which in reality may not be the case if you have very large strings of varying lengths). Of course, if you know that the *contents* of the array will also be constant in addition to its length, then you can say for certain that the function will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

The time required to compare two strings of lengths m and n is O(min{m, n} + 1).  Let's suppose that k is the length of the `word` array and that m is the length of the longest word in `word` and `n` is the length of the input string.  In this case, the function does O(k) string comparisons, each of which take time O(min{m, n} + 1).  Therefore, the runtime is O(k min{m, n} + m).

Now, since m is known to be a constant, we can simplify this and say that the runtime will be O(min{m, n} + 1).  If all of the strings in `word` are fixed constants, then m is a constant and the runtime is O(min{1, n} + 1) = O(1) and your hash function runs in constant time.  Otherwise, if they're unboundedly long, the only thing you can claim is that the runtime is O(min{m, n} + 1).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

your function has complexity O(N<sup>2</sup>), as it has 2 inputs:

1. s - your string (length N<sub>1</sub>)
2. word - array (length N<sub>2</sub>)

so, you complexity will be O(N<sub>1</sub>*N<sub>2</sub>), which can be simplified to O(N<sup>2</sup>)

if length N<sub>2</sub> is really const, then function will have complexity O(N<sub>1</sub>) in worst case.

if length N<sub>1</sub> also consts - then we have O(1) complexity

Comment: @arshajii in this particular case - yes, and we can say that function is just O(N)

Comment: length of input word, as compareTo is generally internal for loop

Answer (score 0):

This function is O(1) if `word` is constant.

`s.length()` runs in constant time regardless of the length of s.

The time it takes to run `word[i].compareTo(s)` is bounded by the length of `word[i]`.  As long as `word` doesn't change, this means there is an upper bound for the time it takes to run the entire for loop.

So there's an upper bound on the time this function takes to run, and the function is O(1).

If `word` can change, I believe this function would be O(n) where n is the size of `word`.  However, if the elements of `word` have increasing lengths, `word[i].compareTo(s)` will be bounded by larger and larger numbers, so the length of `s` might begin to matter.  Perhaps the complexity is actually O(n^2).  I don't know, and now I'm curious myself.